# Table header not showing

Tags: php

I have a certain condition that shows specific HTML table. The condition was met but when I view my modal which the HTML Table must be seen, there's no changes but when I check dev tools PREVIEW theres a table header exist.

When I remove the certain condition, table header will show but even theres a condtion and the condition was met, there's no table header showing. I don't know what is happening.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        echo 'I was here';
        echo '<table class="table table-responsive-md table-striped text-left" id="project-table">';
        echo '<thead>';
        echo  '<tr>';
        echo    '<th style="width: 10%">QTY</th>';
        echo    '<th style="width: 12%">Unit</th>';
        echo    '<th>Particulars</th>';
        echo    '<th style="width: 25%">BOM Ref/Acct Code</th>';
        echo   '<th style="width: 18%">Amount</th>';
        echo  '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';
        echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
?>
```

If you remove the condition, the table will show. Maybe because of my condition but what I want to know is why is it working perfectly in PREVIEW dev tools but not showing in my modal?

[Notice that in the PREVIEW dev tools a table exist but in my modal there no table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnqe9.png)

[Other image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0utW.png)

Comment: did you check `form` has `method="post"` ?? `var_dump($_POST)` and check if `$_POST['data']` exist

Comment: What I did was append the modal body and it solve the issue of $_POSTs because in that scenario I just use the data-target to show the modal.

Comment: @jEIZART It looks like your condition `$_POST['data']` is going to false. Provide your form code so we can see what is the problem?

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Already solve the issue sir, I made a mistake by not appending its body and just use its bootstrap data-target attribute which causes no changes because html and php run at the same time .